# owasp zap api with generate param

Tags: api, owasp, pseudo-random-number-generator

my api is:

```
localhost/api/aut/1111111111111111
```

I wanted a script that generate a code of 16 numeric and test possibility the result 200 or 404

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you *really* want that?

There will be FFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF possible combinations, which is ~ 1.844674407371E+19 in decimal.

Say you can make 1000 requests a second (which is pretty high, but lets go with it)
That means it will take you:

- 1.844674407×10¹⁶ seconds, which is
- 3.074457346×10¹⁴ minutes, which is
- 5.124095576×10¹² hours, which is
- 213503982334 days, which is
- 584942417 years

Yes, its possible to write a ZAP script to test every possible combination, but that doesn't mean its a sensible thing to do.